# Why are there no nonabelian Lie groups with dimension two?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've been asked this immediately after been asked to show that the structure constants $c_{ijk}$ are totally antisymmetric, so I suppose there must be a connection, although I can't figure out where.

I'm really confused about this. A quick search took me to this:
[Example of two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223496/example-of-two-dimensional-non-abelian-lie-algebra)

and to this: [Geometry and Quantum Field Theory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hs4uGmcLkmIC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=two%20dimensional%20lie%20groups%20all%20abelian&source=bl&ots=zaSjxn7y-z&sig=O_a06TstzPheBuGU-F_lxeA4lMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBmoVChMIwKeQ6LbFyAIVSc0UCh3usQIt#v=onepage&q=two%20dimensional%20lie%20groups%20all%20abelian&f=false), from which I quote:

> An example of a Lie group of dimension 2 with a non-abelian Lie algebra is the matrix Lie group
>   $$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\bigg|\,a\in\mathbb{R}^+,\,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ In fact, it is not hard to show that, up to isomorphism, this is the only connected non-abelian Lie group of dimension 2 (...).

The author refers first to the algebra and then to the group, so that makes my confusion worse.

So are there, in fact, non-abelian Lie groups of dimension 2? Or is it the algebra that can be non-abelian? If so, how should I argue that, however, the group must be abelian?

Comment: Lie groups are topological groups where the group action is analytic (or at least smooth); Lie algebras are vector spaces with an extra operation $[\cdot, \cdot]$ satisfying the Jacobi formula. The link between the two is the tangent space $T_1 G$ at the origin in a Lie group $G$ is a Lie algebra, the operation being the Lie bracket for vector fields $X, Y\in T_1 G$. It's not a one-to-one correspondence, though, and the situation with infinite dimension, Lie algebras over finite fields, etc. is more complicated.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there is no 2-d non-abelian Lie group?

Comment: Actually, my guess is that you were asked to show that a *particular* Lie Group has no $2$-$D$ Lie *subgroup*.

Comment: Oh no, I was asked this verbatim in a workshop sheet, so then yes, I guess they wanted to ask something else.

Comment: @CalGibson I'm assuming you're actually on the same course as I am since we have the same issue 9 hours apart. I am pretty sure the lecturer meant to ask: *"Why are there nonabelian Lie groups with dimension one?"* If you look at the notes there is a comment under **One Dimensional Groups** that states *"all 1 dim Lie Groups are abelian"* with *Proof: (See exercise)*. So I'm going to prove that and just state he must have made a typo by referring to an the abelian dim 2 matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lie Group
$$
G = \left\{\pmatrix{a&b\\0&1} : a \in \Bbb R^+,b \in \Bbb R\right\}
$$
is indeed non-abelian.  In particular, note that

$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1} \neq
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
The Lie algebra of this group is also non-abelian (i.e. non-trivial).

I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that there's no such Lie group.