# Non-abelian Lie algebra with two generators

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

So I have a Lie algebra with two generators defined as:

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix} 
      a&b\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
Y=\begin{bmatrix} 
      x&y\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The matrix commutator is:

$$
[X,Y]:=XY-YX.
$$

In which:

$$
XY= \begin{bmatrix} 
      ax&ay\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad YX= \begin{bmatrix} 
      ax&bx\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This was an example [from another user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223496/example-of-two-dimensional-non-abelian-lie-algebra).

*My question is if it is appropriate to say that this algebra has two generators (as opposed to three), and also if the algebra has any unitary representations.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was already remarked at the linked question that there is only one non-abelian Lie algebra of dimension $2$ over $K$ up to isomorphism and that we may take a basis $(x,y)$ such that $[x,y]=x$. In particular, we have only $2$ generators.

As for unitary representations we need to be precise what this is for Lie algebras, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184343/whats-the-appropriate-notion-of-a-unitary-representation-of-a-lie-algebra).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!